# Flutter: Text animation is not playing

Tags: flutter

I want to play a text animation only once in my `flutter` app. For this purpose, I am using this package:

```
animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
```

This is my code:

```
TableRow( children: [
  Column(children:const [Text('Message',style:TextStyle(fontSize: 16))]),
  Column(children:[AnimatedTextKit(
    animatedTexts: [
      TypewriterAnimatedText(
        'Hey, sup!',
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    totalRepeatCount: 1,
  )]),
]),
```

I expect the animation to be played only once. But when I execute the code, the animation doesn't play. It just stays on as a normal text.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the text is animating but the speed is high therefore you are not able to see it, you can add speed manually,

Here's the code snippet you can try:

```
TypewriterAnimatedText(
                'Hey, sup!',
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                speed: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              )
```

Hope it helps